# How to make large binomial coefficient?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I have a potentially-repeated question, but I was unable to find anything about this. So, I need to create a giant binomial coefficient in LaTeX (something around 1000pt). When I compile the below, though, it scales the `\binom{}{}` up, but not the a and b. Is there any way to make the whole thing bigger?

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{1000}{1000}{1000}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \binom{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 8):

By default `cm` fonts are only loaded in a restricted set of sizes.  `fix-cm` allows them to be used as a scalable font.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{1000}{1000}{1000}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \binom{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Latin Modern fonts, provided you fix the `largesymbols` font:

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{ <-> lmex10 }{}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{1000}{1000}\selectfont
$\displaystyle \binom{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Easiest here is just to scale the entire construction to suit your needs using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` functionality:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{!}{1000pt}{$\displaystyle \binom{a}{b}$}
\end{document}
```